# XFCE: Drag-and-drop pointer stuck on some windows

Tags: mouse, xfce, crash, drag-and-drop, smplayer

In some programs like SMPlayer and Clementine when dragging the window with the mouse (for example by accidentally clicking on the program window instead of the media progress bar), the mouse pointer freezes in the dragging-hand state and does not return to the normal cursor when releasing the left mouse button. The keyboard will not take any input at this state, either.

When reacting qickly to this and pressing `Control+Alt+F1`, it is possible to enter the non-GUI logon screen, enter the username and password and restart lightdm with `sudo service lightdm restart`. Else, the system will completely freeze and must be resetted manually.

This only appears to happen in programs that use the classic NT-style windows, such as the mentioned SMPlayer and Clementine (unsure).

What could be the reason for this and is there any way to solve this problem or to release the drag?

To reproduce: Start Ubuntu Studio (/Xubuntu?), install SMPlayer and/or Clementine out of the Software Center and drag the window near the media progress bar on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Ubuntu Studio / xfce -- particularly with applications I've written with PySide, but that may be because those are not full screen, and I move them more often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have same issue, and here is my solution:
the tmp solution is:

```
xfwm4 --replace
```

it will restart xfwm4(I guess) and fix this issue, but when this issue may be occurred again

so I try to downgrade xfwm4, in my case, xfwm version "4.13.0-1mint1+sonya" has this issue(when I upgrade to linux mint 18.3 xfce, it use this version xfwm4), and my old os linut mint 18(it use xfwm4 4.12.3-1ubuntu2) has not this issue, so I try to downgrade, I use following:

```
sudo apt remove xfwm4 -y
sudo apt install xfwm4=4.12.3-1ubuntu2 -y
```

Comment: I see the same problem with v4.14.3 on ArchLinux.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue lately, while using Gimp and/or Netbeans.

What worked for me, was follow this procedure :

1. Switch from graphical tty to a console tty using `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1`
2. Switch back from console tty to graphical tty using `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F7`

That's really all it took to "fix" the cursor.

I didn't even need to login at the console tty. Just switching between ttys did the trick for me.

Comment: Are you using Compton by any chance? I have used Compton because of screen tearing with my Nvidia GPU, but after switching to Compiz, I have not experienced this problem any more. Maybe you're interested in trying to switch your compositing manager to Compiz as well to see if this fixes it completely?

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-F1 does nothing for me.